# ShadowsocksX[2004]: Could not bind

Tags: vps

Shadowsocks cannot connect to the network on MAC and can be used on Windows.

My system log：

```
Jul  3 11:45:54 yaojundeMacBook-Pro ShadowsocksX[2004]: Could not bind
Jul  3 11:46:24 --- last message repeated 29 times ---
Jul  3 11:46:24 yaojundeMacBook-Pro ShadowsocksX[2004]: Could not bind
Jul  3 11:46:54 --- last message repeated 29 times ---
Jul  3 11:46:54 yaojundeMacBook-Pro ShadowsocksX[2004]: Could not bind
Jul  3 11:47:24 --- last message repeated 28 times ---
Jul  3 11:47:24 yaojundeMacBook-Pro ShadowsocksX[2004]: Could not bind
Jul  3 11:47:54 --- last message repeated 29 times ---
Jul  3 11:47:54 yaojundeMacBook-Pro ShadowsocksX[2004]: Could not bind
Jul  3 11:48:24 --- last message repeated 29 times ---
Jul  3 11:48:24 yaojundeMacBook-Pro ShadowsocksX[2004]: Could not bind
How to solve this problem, thank you very much
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with you ,ss isn't work on my mbp and work perfect on my windows.
   You can try [ShadowsocksX-NG](https://github.com/shadowsocks/ShadowsocksX-NG), this is can be used on my Mac.

PS:
      Must be make sure your internet don't have any othder proxy.
Because my mac and windows pc on the same internet and the internet has a proxy.   So,my mac ss doesn't work perfect, but my windows pc work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, this error means that the proxy port is occupied by other programs, you need to modify the Shadowsocks proxy port (default=1080), modify the port file in `⁨Users ▸ ⁨User Name ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨ Application Support⁩ ▸ ⁨ShadowsocksX▸proixy.config`

change to:

```
Listen-address 127.0.0.1:1085
```